# Unable to launch an ios emulator on latest OSX, flutter and xcode version

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Iam running osx 14.0, xcode 15.0.1 and latest avaiable flutterversion an iam trying to run an flutterproject on an ios emulator but i alway get the message "Waiting for connection..." but nothing happend

Flutter doctor reports no problems and i already found solutions like:

- Killing the simulatorprocesss
- Deleting Xcode Developer cache
- Reinstall xcode

None of them worked, so iam closed to reinstall ventura to use xcode 14.2, because that worked fine.

Is there any other work around for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `flutter run` with the `--verbose` flag, maybe you'll see some suspicious logs